# Google drive file: set local modification date

Tags: ios, macos, google-drive-api, nsdateformatter

I need to set the local file modification date to file in Google Drive. First I tried to set using drive.file.insert API that didn't work. In SO it is discussed that file modification can be done using drive.file.patch API. Below is the code that Am using to update file modification date. But when I try this I am getting error.

> An error occurred: Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Invalid value for: Invalid format: "2013-09-261T15:09:57Z" is malformed at "1T15:09:57Z")"

Code:

```
-(void)updateFileModificationDate:(GTLDriveFile*)file
{    
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +HHMM"];
    file.modifiedDate = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithRFC3339String:[rfc3339DateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate]];
    GTLQueryDrive *getQuery =
    [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesPatchWithObject:file fileId:file.identifier];
    getQuery.setModifiedDate = YES;
    [self.driveService executeQuery:getQuery completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveFile* object, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"New file mod date:%@",object.modifiedDate);
        }
    }];

}
```

Please help me to find out the correct date format. Will be grateful if answer is in Objective-C.
**EDIT**
Another question is, Whichever format date we set, Drive SDK should handle converting it to the required format during API call. It seems that it's not happening so. Is it a defect in Google Drive Objective-c SDK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the question...

```
"malformed at "1T15:09:57Z")"
```

You're trying to set the date to the 261st of September, 2013

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource, "modifiedDate ... formatted RFC 3339 timestamp." So your format is correct.